# mvc3 .net Unobtrusive Javascript - works sometimes, but not always

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

The validation sometimes works when tabbing but not always.  For example, load webpage, delete (backspace) data from required field, tab - validation sometimes fires, sometimes doesn't.

If I delete the same field's data and submit the form, validation fires and submission fails.  Then validation on this field works correctly from then on.

Is this the standard functionality of unobtrusive javascript?

Comment: Is it standard functionality of unobtrusive JavaScript to "sometimes" work? Come on, do you really think we are going to say "yes"? Strip back your code to the basics, get it working, then gradually enhance. That's what coding is all about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the following script to enable validation when tabing out of a field:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').data('validator').settings.onfocusout = function (element) {
        $(element).valid(); 
    };
});
```

Comment: Darin, as ever, a great answer that works great.  Many thanks.